# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview

I have been using the same method to inflate all my other widgets in all my other fragments, but it's not working here for some reason.

ResultFragment.java:

```
public class ResultFragment extends Fragment {

  private WebView webPageResult;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, parent, false);

    webPageResult = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webPageResult);
    webPageResult.loadUrl("google.com");

    return v;
  }

}
```

fragment_result.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.danielbalagula.gift.ResultFragment">

  <WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webPageResult"   
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inflating the wrong layout, try to inflate `fragment_result` instead of `fragment_question`.

Use `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result, parent, false);`

Comment: I guess that's the risk with copy/pasting